# Laravel set class if radio button selected

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have these radio buttons:

[image]

It's a separate Laravel blade component.

```
@props(['active'])

@php
$classes = ($active ?? false)
            ? 'group relative border bg-white py-3 px-4 flex items-center justify-center text-black text-sm font-semibold uppercase focus:outline-none sm:flex-1 shadow-sm cursor-pointer transition duration-150 ease-in-out'
            : 'group relative border py-3 px-4 flex items-center justify-center text-gray-300 text-sm font-semibold uppercase focus:outline-none sm:flex-1 shadow-sm cursor-pointer duration-150 ease-in-out';
@endphp

<label {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => $classes]) }}>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="{{ $slot }}" class="sr-only">
      <span> {{ $slot }} </span>
        <span class="absolute -inset-px pointer-events-none" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</label>
```

I call it on a different page like so:

```
<x-product-size>XS</x-product-size>
```

How do I change the variable if it's selected? I can only find solutions on changing it depending on the route by doing something like this:

```
<x-nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
                            {{ __('Dashboard') }}
</x-nav-link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JS for this purpose.
add an id to your radio input for example radioID.

```
<input type="radio" id="radioID" name="size" value="{{ $slot }}" class="sr-only">
```

and:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {          
            $('#radioID').on('change', function () {
                var selected = this.value;
             if(selected == "XS") // or a variable
             var slot = "some data";
             {
              $("#spanID").append(' + slot + ');
              }
           });
         });
</script>
```

If you want to add active to a div, span or something other you can do it like this using their CLASS or ID:

```
$('.someclass').first().addClass('active');
$('#someid').first().addClass('active');
```